# Why do I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I build an imageView with JavaFX?

Tags: exception, javafx

I have various places in my JavaFx app where I insert images(png/gif). It usually works with one exception. What I do:

- I put the images in a specific directory under resources.
- I load them like this:

  ImageView openView = new ImageView("/pics/logo.png");

An alternative that also works is:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = classParameter.getResourceAsStream("/pics/logo.png");
Image image = new Image(resourceAsStream);
ImageView openView = new ImageView(image);
```

The problem:
There is one gif that has a white background. When I insert it in the app it works, but if I insert the same gif after it is transformed (to add transparency for background) I get :

```
ObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.image.Image@2ac5919d, name: exception, value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096]
```

If I open it for view, the transformed gif is displayed as expected.

Any ideas on why is this exception thrown?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.gif.GIFImageLoader2$LZWDecoder.readString(GIFImageLoader2.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.gif.GIFImageLoader2.decodeImage(GIFImageLoader2.java:148)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.gif.GIFImageLoader2.load(GIFImageLoader2.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(ImageStorage.java:368)
    at com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage.loadAll(ImageStorage.java:328)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.loadAll(PrismImageLoader2.java:119)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PrismImageLoader2.<init>(PrismImageLoader2.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.loadImage(QuantumToolkit.java:648)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.loadImage(Image.java:1036)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.initialize(Image.java:785)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:599)
    at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:167)
    at helpers.Helpers.setImageView(Helpers.java:173)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace of the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: stack trace added - sorry bout that

Comment: The error is emanating from internal JavaFX code. It's possible you have a bad GIF file—check it. If the GIF file turns out to be fine then this may be a bug in JavaFX.

Comment: well the gif seems to be fine when opened with any picture viewer - even when I open it with the IDE (although it doesn't move in the IDE) - will try to use another tool then to reconvert it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using another gif editing tool. So the problem was the conversion. Even if the initial gif seemed fine, under the hood it made JavaFx crash. (Won't share here the name of the tools that work and that didn't work, since it may be against stackoverflow policy).